# Google prompt won't show up after I flashed my phone

Tags: google, 2-step-verification, find-my-device

2-Step enabled, and I keeped backup codes.

This is what I did:

- Before I flashed my phone, I logout my google account.
- Then after I flashed my phone, I logged in google accout from my phone by using backup codes.
- In [Google - Your devices page](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity) I signed out old devices.

But when I checked the [Google prompts page](https://myaccount.google.com/two-step-verification/prompt), it still showed my old phone(the name is the old one).

[image: old prompt phone]

And when I tried to log in somewhere, the "Google prompt" didn't pop up. I have to use backup codes or Authenticator.

**Is there a way that I can fix this? or just disable "Google prompt"?** I'm OK with using Authenticator and backup codes when phone is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging out should have stopped the prompts on the old device. Check under logged in devices and log it out manually.

You can check the prompt-supported devices you are logged into right now at *Manager your account* → *Security* → *Google Prompts* → enter your password.

When your new device is considered "trusted" and supports prompts, you'll start receiving prompts on it automatically.

About turning it off: you can't, as far as I know.

Also, see [How to disable Google Prompts?](https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/60209294/how-to-disable-google-prompts)  on Google Help.

Comment: Well the "Manager your account --> Security --> Google Prompts" page is showed as my screenshot. I now think it may just be google's issue, not my phone's.

Comment: :) It will start appearing soon if you have the Gapps and the safety net is passed. You can also check https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/2fa-google-phone-prompt-not-working.4354859/